# Need to post array of values in a url objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, post

Hi am new to development I need to post the below array in a url kindly guide me to solve this issue.

```
{
  "order": {
    "email": "foo@example.com",
    "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
    "send_receipt": true,
    "send_fulfillment_receipt": true,
    "line_items": [
      {
        "variant_id": 447654529,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration =   [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
[sessionConfiguration setAllowsCellularAccess:YES];
[sessionConfiguration setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{ @"Accept" : @"application/json" }];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

NSString *datastring = @"{\"order\": {\"email\": \"foo@example.com\",\"fulfillment_status\": \"fulfilled\",\"send_receipt\":true,\"send_fulfillment_receipt\": true,\"line_items\": [{\"variant_id\": 447654529,\"quantity\": 1}]}}";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR LINK"]];
NSLog(@"url=%@",url);

// Configure the Request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPBody = [datastring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

// post the request and handle response
NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
     // Handle the Response
     if(error)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please check your internet connection: %@", [error description]]);

         // Update the View
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             // Hide the Loader
             //   [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window animated:YES];                                                          
             [self ShowConnectionError];
         });
         return;
     }
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         NSString *retVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"retVal=%@",retVal);
     });
}];

// Initiate the Request
[postDataTask resume];
```

Comment: Yes in "YourString" , you can pass the string

Comment: its not a string its array.. please see my question

Comment: This is a json string

Comment: could you please edit your answer based on the above json string

Comment: it does nothing. Shows a warning " Unused variable 'postDataTask'"

Comment: Then how can you get "Unused variable postDataTask" it is used below [postDataTask resume];

Comment: Yes now its working but received error "retVal={"errors":{"order":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}"